# Styling an iframe for responsive design

Tags: iframe, responsive-design

So I've never styled an iframe before! Obviously you grab it's element name, class or Id and style it like normal however I'm having troubles styling it over the element.style styles that have been placed on it by a wordpress plugin. There's got to be a way to make this iframe a bit more responsive than it is now.

Visit the [website here](http://onlinewebdraft.com/residential/mortgage-renewal/), then scroll to the bottom and hit the "CALCULATE" button under the MORTGAGE CALCULATOR. I'm trying to give this iframe a bit of a responsive touch as it has none right now.

I thought if I just styled it's id name then it would be fine but no luck! Then I tried just iframe.

```
html #MLCalcFrame {
    border: 2px solid red !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
}



html iframe {
    width: 100% !important;
    border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

What would the best way be to add some responsive styles to this iframe?

Comment: It looks like some of the styles are being removed by the plugin's javascript, as adding them back with firebug works fine. you'll have to either figure out how to stop the plugin from removing them, or add them back after the plugin does its thing

Comment: When I click the calculate button on your site, the only thing I get is an 'x' indicating I can close something, but I can't see what that something is. Also, you should post the existing code that's causing problems in a jsfiddle or something similar, as the code for your site may change going forward, or your site may go offline, which will render this question and any answers completely ineffective.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback hair raisin. I however am not that skilled with looking to javascript and plugin files. I will have to set up a different plugin that has already been created with responsive in mind.

Comment: I'll be sure to keep this in mind for future questions MattD.